# To show that there exists a right and left inverse matrix for $A$

Tags: matrices

How to show that, if $A$ element of $\mathbb{C}_{p\times q}$, then there exist a left invertible matrix $B$ and a right invertible matrix $C$ such that $A=BC$? use singular value decomposition

Comment: Hint: what is the singular value decomposition of $A$? Do you see any "somewhat invertible" matrices which you can use to find $B$ and $C$?

Answer (score 2):

Think of linear maps rather than matrices. So $A\colon \mathbb{C}^q\to\mathbb{C}^p$ is a linear map. Let $r$ be the rank of $A$, and pick an $r$-dimensional subspace $V\subseteq\mathbb{C}^q$ whose intersection with the null space of $A$ is trivial. Let $C'\colon\mathbb{C}^q\to V$ be the projection which vanishes on the null space of $A$, and let $D'\colon V\to\mathbb{C}^p$ be the restriction of $A$ to $V$. Finally, let $D\colon V\to\mathbb{C}^r$ be an isomorphism, and let $C=DC'$, $B=B'D^{-1}$.

I leave the details up to you. (Hint: $C'$ is surjective, $B'$ is injective.)

Comment: I want to do it with Singular value decomposition but I didnt understood this solution.